# Evaluate inequality in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, boolean-logic, pharo, boolean-expression, squeak

Since I am not aware of any inequality operator in Pharo smalltalk, it makes it difficult to check for inequality of a string. This is my current code:

```
[ contact password = contact confirmPassword and: firstTime = false and: (contact password = '' ifTrue:[^false])]   whileFalse: [ code]
```

namely this part:
    `(contact password = '' ifTrue:[^false])`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to check if a string is not empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an inequality operator,

`a ~= b`

although it's rarely used as it is often better to just write `a = b ifFalse: [ ...]`

That's not all however, `and:` accepts a block, not a boolean

so

```
contact password = contact confirmPassword and: firstTime = false
```

should actually be

```
contact password = contact confirmPassword and: [ firstTime = false ]
```

if you want the shorthand variant, you can use `&`

```
contact password = contact confirmPassword & (firstTime = false)
```

The difference is that the `and:` block is evaluated only if the receiver is true. This is important if the `and:` block relies on the truthness of the the receiver, such as `a ~= 0 and: [ x / a = b ]`. This would be a ZeroDivide error if you used `&` or forgot the block.

Finally you can check string emptiness by sending it `isEmpty` or `ifEmpty:` message, e.g.

`myString ifEmpty: [ ... ]`
or equivalently
`myString isEmpty ifTrue: [ ... ]`

So you can write your condition for example as follows:

```
contact password = contact confirmPassword & firstTime not & contact password isEmpty ifTrue: [ ^ false ]
```

Comment: Just a side note: `myString = ''` will correctly evaluate to true if `myString` is empty.

Answer (score 5):

Pharo **does have** inequality:

```
anObject ~= otherObject
```

This is equivalent to

```
(anObject = otherObject) not
```

What Pharo does not have (along with any other Smalltalk or pure object language) is such thing as an "operator" (which is a mathematical function).

In Pharo, both `=` and `~=` are not operators but simple messages you send to an object. In this case means: take object `anObject` and send to him the message `~=` with parameter `otherObject`.

It has certain practical consequences like the fact that you can define your own `=`, `~=` messages... and you can check how they are implemented (or even modify them, though I do not recommend it to you if you want to keep the system running :) )

About the empty string, you have several better ways to do it than what you are doing now, this is the simplest (and better):

```
aString ifEmpty: [ ^ false ].
```

... or you can also check for nil (sometimes you need it):

```
aString isEmptyOrNil ifTrue: [ ^ false ].
```

... or you could check size (zero means empty, isn't?):

```
aString size = 0 ifTrue: [ ^ false ]
```

There are others, but these come to mind fast. Please notice that the best way to do it is using `ifEmpty:` message. Also if you look for implementors of `ifEmpty:`, in Pharo is easy with spotter (press shift+enter) or selecting `ifEmpty:` and pressing cmd+m (if mac) or ctrl+m (if using linux/windows), you will find in the same class implementing it also a family of interesting messages you can use: `ifEmpty:`, `ifNotEmpty:`, etc.

EDIT: formatting.

EDIT: I would write your code like this:

```
[ contact password = contact confirmPassword 
  and: [ firstTime not 
  and: [ contact password notEmpty ]]]
whileFalse: [ code ]
```

Notice following:

- the square brackets for `and:` parameters. This is because they are also messages (not operators) who receive a block parameter who is evaluated lazily, then making expression much more efficient.
- `firstTime not` is equivalent (but more legible in Pharo programming style) than `firstTime = false`.
- `contact password notEmpty` is how you check for empty without passing control to a block if empty happens. This is equivalent to `contact password isEmpty not` which is also a valid way of writing the code (but less concise).